# Iptables don't load balance

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking

I have consulted multiple tutorials to achieve load balancing over two internet connections. However, all traffic continues to get routed over the default route with the lowest metric, and I can't figure out why

```
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

ip rule delete from all fwmark 0x1
ip rule delete from all fwmark 0x2

ip rule flush
ip rule add lookup main priority 32766

iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -A PREROUTING  -t mangle -m mark --mark 0x0 -m statistic \
         --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A PREROUTING  -t mangle -m mark --mark 0x0 -m statistic \
         --mode nth --every 2 --packet 1 -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -j CONNMARK --save-mark

ip route flush table wlp3s0
ip route flush table enp0s20u2
ip route add default via 46.37.116.1 table wlp3s0
ip route add 46.37.116.0/23 dev wlp3s0 table wlp3s0
ip route add default via 192.168.42.129 table enp0s20u2
ip route add 192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20u2 table enp0s20u2
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup wlp3s0 priority 1000
ip rule add fwmark 2 lookup enp0s20u2 priority 1000

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -m mark --mark 1 -j SNAT --to-source 46.37.116.111
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -m mark --mark 2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.42.130

echo 0 > "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlp3s0/rp_filter"
echo 0 > "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/enp0s20u2/rp_filter"

ip route flush cache
```

ip route:

```
ip route
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20u2  src 192.168.42.130  metric 207 
default via 46.37.116.1 dev wlp3s0  src 46.37.116.111  metric 303 
46.37.116.0/23 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 46.37.116.111  metric 303 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20u2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.130  metric 207
```

ip route list all table wlp3s0

```
default via 46.37.116.1 dev wlp3s0 
46.37.116.0/23 dev wlp3s0  scope link
```

ip route list all table enp0s20u2

```
default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20u2 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20u2  scope link
```

ip rule

```
0:  from all lookup local 
1000:   from all fwmark 0x1 lookup wlp3s0 
1000:   from all fwmark 0x2 lookup enp0s20u2 
32766:  from all lookup main
```